# Android: how to refresh screen when user touches the outside search?

Tags: android, mobile

I need to know how to detect user touching outside search. Steps to reproduce:

click on search icon. This brings up standard search dialog.  Touch outside search dialog. I need to detech this?  Why?  becuase I have a header which is replaced during the search. I hide it during the search but when outside search I need to restore my other header.  So how do I detect action outside search dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `TouchListener` to your whole `View`:

```
final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if(event.getX() == x && event.getY() == y) // x and y are within the search box
               {
                  //you clicked inside the search box,do nothing
               }
               if(event.getX() == outsideSearchBox && event.getY() == outsideSearchBox)
               {
                   //do your stuff
               }  
               return true;
        }
    });
```

You just need to determine the coordinates where your search box is, and then you can apply the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is an onDismiss listener that can be registered using the SearchManager.  This tells you when the search dialog is closed.  So I implemented the onDismiss() method in my activity.  In create I used the ServiceManager to register my activity as an OnDismiss listener.  It works fine.